# Dockerfile Here Document not working - /bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -

Tags: dockerfile

I get an error when using a here-document

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs

FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN <<EOF
    set -eux
EOF
```

Commands

```
$ docker build . --no-cache
[+] Building 2.1s (9/9) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 125B                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs                                                                                                                                                                                     0.7s 
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs@sha256:250ce669e1aeeb5ffb892b18039c3f0801466536cb4210c8eb2638e628859bfd                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:focal                                                                                                                                                                                       0.7s 
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:focal@sha256:450e066588f42ebe1551f3b1a535034b6aa46cd936fe7f2c6b0d72997ec61dbd                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN <<EOF (set -eux)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.4s 
------
 > [2/2] RUN <<EOF (set -eux):
#9 0.320 /bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c     set -eux
]: exit code: 2
```

Buildkit is ON.

Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks